# I am getting a break in my android emulator: failed to load libc++_shared exception dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file \"/system/…"

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, chromecast

I am trying to implement a routine to cast a video stream using LibVLCSharp but when it gets to where I invoke the core.initialise command, it triggers the above error.

Here's the code in question:

```
        private void BroadcastStream() //string[] args)
    {
        var serverIpAddress = "192.168.1.101";
        var streamUrl = $"rtsp://{serverIpAddress}:554/stream.sdp";

        try
        {
            LibVLCSharp.Shared.Core.Initialize();

            var libVlc = new LibVLC();
            var media = new Media(libVlc, "fe48f269-4f89-4c58-afd4-04c2e2e3f10f.MP4");

            media.AddOption(
                $":sout=#transcode{{vcodec=h264,vb=0,scale=0,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}}:rtp{{mux=ts,sdp={streamUrl}}}");
            media.AddOption(":sout-keep");

            var player = new MediaPlayer(media);

            player.Play();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

    }
```

I am using using "LibVLCSharp.Shared;" in the code file and as per instructions I invoked "LibVLCSharpFormsRenderer.Init();" inside "protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)" in the Android project's MainActivity.cs file.

So, how do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I loaded the default LibVLSharp.forms library from Nuget for all the projects (iOS, Android & UWP) and that's what caused the issue. I uninstalled the library for iOS and Android and installed their own specific LibVLSharp libraries and it appears to be ok now (at least it no more breaks at core.initialise).